# Cannot connect AWS MS SQL database in Visual Studio / SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have created an instance of MS SQL database on Amazon Web Services. but when I give in the Endpoint ,the port, username , password and connect I get this error

[image]

I have configured the security groups and the VPC to allow all Traffic ,ports and also the db was created  Publicly Accessible as Yes

Comment: Does your firewall allow outgoing connections on the SQL Server port?

Comment: Thankyou DavidG, but unfortunately that doesnt seem to work, I tried to add the ports (1433) and even turned off the Firewall and tried the connection

Comment: One more item to check - on the DB Server Properties -> Security make sure you have "SQL Server and Windows Authentication" selected...

Comment: i guess that setting can be changed only after you connect to the database; but here, I cannot get through the connection phase...

Comment: i guess that setting can be changed only after you connect to the database; but here, I cannot get through the connection phase...